# List view item indicator (>)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have noticied that in some android menues, a list view is shown that lists items with a (>) icon on the right. It is something like the expandable list but the arrow aims right. Is this something built-in, or have I to do it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make your list view row layout like that.

You can set image in Drawable left in your row layout

Answer (score 2):

It is called [Group Indicator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setGroupIndicator%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) and it is available by default in [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

if you don't want Group Indicator to be visible, then you have to use `setGroupIndicator(null)`. But by default it will be visible for any Expandable ListView you create.

And when it shows an arrow towards left it means the group is in collapsed state and when it points bottom it means the group is in expanded state.

Comment: My guess for the down vote (wasn't mine) would be because you didn't answer the question.  The OP said the icon was on the right side and points to the right, the stock indicators for an expandable list view are on the left.

Comment: Yes, I thank you for investing your time answering the question, but your answer has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Damn. I didn't look properly at the word "right". Then I deserve it.

Answer (score 1):

In ListView

**   >    Right Arrow on right side of the row,**

is putted to navigate to another Activity.

That arrow is some-time ImageButton, by clicking on it;
uoy can go to other activity.